# Make my FB catalog product image (microdata) different from my share image (og:image)

Tags: facebook-opengraph, microdata, json-ld, facebook-marketing-api

I cannot figure out a way to distinguish the image url in the og:image metatag from the image url in the product microdata. I've been searching for the answer for days.

The situation is that I have an image url in the og:image metatag that is created specifically for sharing, but I would like to use a simple product image url (different from the share image) when the product is added to my Facebook Catalog through my pixel, using microdata. Unfortunately when the product is added to my catalog, it pulls the og image instead of the image in the product microdata.

You can see an example when you look at the source code here:
https://www.storefrontier.com/product/atl-the-original-martha
There you will see my og metatags and JSON-LD microdata . Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?
Thanks!